# Deploying Applications other than WebApp using Azure Resource Manager

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I am currently looking into using ARM to deploy new environments of our Azure Components. We have a lot of web apis that are deployed to Cloud Services, since we need access to the underlying OS to get CPU usage for App Dynamics metrics. When reading through ARM, it seems as if they are deprecating Cloud Services, but I have some confusion about what is replacing it. I see that you can create Web Apps using this and use Publish from Visual Studio to deploy the app it, but I see no options for Cloud Services. So what is the preferred method to do this? Creating a VM and deploying using Web Deploy? What about VM scaling. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

My company is in the process of moving a legacy app to Azure using Cloud Services and we were concerned about the future of Cloud Services. Since we are somewhat early into the project and would like to use the ARM model we thought it would be easier to make a move now if we knew the future. After a few conversations with project leads at Microsoft on this topic we were only told that we should continue working with Cloud Services as they would continue to be supported.

It's quite clear that the move to ARM was not well thought out in terms of direction and consequences of existing services that many people are already using. Reading between the lines I would say that there is no plan to convert Cloud Services from the ASM to ARM model.

Comment: So they said to continue using the ASM model for deployment? Interesting

Answer (score 0):

If application insights (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/application-insights/) are sufficient for your monitoring needs, then you can use web apps. These can be deployed via ARM, and can automatically deploy from a git repo or web deploy package. See this example:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-web-app-github-deploy

The issue here that you may be trying to do operations which are restricted by the web app sandbox.

Failing that, you can use an ARM template to set up a VM and then invoke a custom site extension which will run powershell code to do further provisioning. This powershell code can fetch any package that you may want to install. See this ARM template for example: https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/9ad72f1f5f0008c14311be79eee036b871712394/201-list-storage-keys-windows-vm

Once the VM is created you would be able to modify it and scale as needed.

Comment: And you use Web Deploy to deploy the app there? I just don't see the benefit of doing that over a Cloud Service

Comment: If you're using WebApps, you can use WebDeploy, FTP or even deploy via Git.  If you want to go the VM route, I would look at Virtual Machine Scale Sets as a replacement for Cloud Services.  VMSS will autoscale and you can deploy to them using DSC, PowerShell, WebDeploy, FTP etc.  There are examples for VMSS in github, and if you have access to VS, the VMSS template there is a little simpler than the gh examples.

Comment: an additional solution for your "issue" is looking at Service Fabric, which is fully ARM supported